# Remove duplicate rows of matrix and cell together in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, duplicates, unique

I have a matrix A with 30000 rows and a cell B with the same row number. I would like to remove duplicate rows. If it's only a matrix A, I can use the function unique. But for A(matrix) and B(Cell) together, how can I proceed? Many thanks!

The examples of A and B are shown below. Row 4 and 5 are duplicate (for both A and B) while Row 5 and 6 should not be taken as duplicate.

A

```
1   2   3   4   
11  12  13  14
21  22  23  24
31  32  33  34
31  32  33  34
31  32  33  34
41  42  43  44
```

B

```
a
b
c
d
d
e
f
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with the second return value from [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html):

```
[C,ia,ic] = unique(A,'rows',setOrder)
```

`ia` gives you the indices into `A` of the unique rows. If you do this on your matrix `A`, you get:

```
>> [~,iA,~] = unique(A,'rows','first')
iA =

   1
   2
   3
   4
   7
```

(I used the option `'first'` because it seemed more natural to me to return row 4 than row 5. You can use the default `'last'` if you prefer, as long as you're consistent.)

Since `B` is a cell array, you don't need the `'rows'` option:

```
>> [~,iB,~] = unique(B,'first')
iB =

   1
   2
   3
   4
   6
   7
```

This tells us that, despite what matrix `A` tells us, row 4 is unique from row 6. If we take the set union of these two, we get:

```
>> uAB = union(iA,iB)
uAB =

   1
   2
   3
   4
   6
   7
```

Now you should have the indices of all of the unique rows:

```
>> A(uAB,:)
ans =

    1    2    3    4
   11   12   13   14
   21   22   23   24
   31   32   33   34
   31   32   33   34
   41   42   43   44

>> B(uAB)
ans =
{
  [1,1] = a
  [2,1] = b
  [3,1] = c
  [4,1] = d
  [5,1] = e
  [6,1] = f
}
```

Comment: Thanks @LuisMendo, your comment made me look at my answer again and realize that I had put the wrong code for `iB`. I'll fix that now.

Comment: I see. I hadn't realized that

Comment: @LuisMendo I had simply given the version without `'first'` right after the warning to stay consistent with `'first'` or `'last'`. ;)